# How can I build Gameboy Development Kit 2.1.5 on a modern Unix/Mac platform?

Tags: software, apple-macintosh, game-boy, software-development-kit, unix

Continuing with my quest to build the Infinity Game Boy Color [source code](https://github.com/infinity-gbc/infinity), I am trying to build the Unix source of [GBDK 2.1.5](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gbdk/files/gbdk/2.1.5/) on my macOS El Capitan machine.

Trying to `make` the files in the `lib` directory gives me this error:

```
➜  lib git:(master) ✗ make
../bin/lcc -Wa-l -c -o floor.o floor.s
../bin/lcc: ../bin/lcc: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [floor.o] Error 126
```

Running `file` on the `lcc` binary reveals that an ancient version of the lcc compiler was bundled with the 2.1.5 release:

```
➜  lib git:(master) ✗ file ../bin/lcc
../bin/lcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped
```

Ok, this won't work on my machine.  I'll attempt to fix this by switching all references to `lcc` to `clang` in the Makefile.

The next dependency is a tool called `maccer`, Michael Hope's macro preprocessor.  This tool has the same issue as lcc:

```
➜  lib git:(master) ✗ make
../bin/maccer -o floor.s floor.ms
../bin/maccer: ../bin/maccer: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [floor.s] Error 126
➜  lib git:(master) ✗ file ../bin/maccer
../bin/maccer: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped
```

I can't for the life of me find the source of this, but I did find a modified version called [MaccerX](http://gendev.spritesmind.net/page-macX.html).

### Question

Is MaccerX a viable alternative to the original maccer?  Has anyone successfully built GBDK 2.1.5 on a modern platform with a modern compiler?  I expect to run into more of these issues as I attempt to use SDK tools from 15+ years ago.

Well I found [maccer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gbdk/files/maccer/0.25/), it was in the same GBDK repo.  Looking to see if I can make a native build now.  I'm not sure the maccer source and be built without doc++ (whatever that is), so looking into that now.

Comment: That error is commonly for the binary is not compatible with your processor.  The 80386 appears to be 32-bit and your computer is most likely 64-bit.  Do you have the 64/32-bit compatibility libraries installed?

Comment: @RomaH I know that's the error.  The problem is that the libraries are bundled with the source code.  So I'm in the process of painstakingly building each bundled dependency from scratch or moving to a more modern tool available on my system.

Comment: Any answer is going to primarily be about getting libraries and binaries working on modern equipment. This feels off-topic. If this project is being maintained you'd be better off communicating directly with them. If you are resurrecting an abandoned project you probably just need to take this to a general computing forum of some sort.

Comment: @jdv Can you offer any suggestions on how this could be edited to be more on-topic?  Or do you believe this question is unsalvageable for Retrocomputing.

Comment: @RomaH The 80386 is 32-bit, yes.

Comment: That's also a Linux binary, whereas you are using Mac OS X.

Comment: @RomaH The problem is not the number of bits. Modern macOS computers will happily run 32 bit binaries. The problem is that the binaries are in ELF format which is the Linux binary format. The macOS equivalent to ELF is called  Mach-O.

Comment: @JAL are you trying to get to the point of cross compiling the oriinal source code for an emulator or are you hoping to run it natively on macOS?

Comment: This is a very interesting project! Is there a specific reason you can't dual boot or use a VM?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using C for Game Boy software. [The currently available toolchains are lacking](https://gist.github.com/ISSOtm/4f4d335c3fd258ad0dfc7d4d615409fd).

Answer (score 9):

Build it on a Linux VM of the era. The tools will probably expect command lines of GCC of the time, as well as libraries current at that time.

I'd say something like Debian 2.0 or Redhat 7 (not RHEL!) should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search for macOS versions of the Gameboy Development kit and I found this:

https://github.com/x43x61x69/gbdk-osx

it doesn't build on my Mac but it looks like the issue is just one of locating build directories properly. However, it does include the source code of `lcc` and `maccer`.